# Deleting an item in dict while looping

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I am using scrapy to get some data from a website 
here is some code of my spider

```
for item in response.css('div.project-content  table tr'):
    var["installment"] = item.css(' td::text').extract_first()
    if var['installment'] is None:
        del var['installment']
    print(var)
```

it looks so simple right! 
now here is my output

```
{}
{'installment': '1st Installment'}
{'installment': '2nd Installment'}
{'installment': '3rd Installment'}
{'installment': '4th Installment'}
{'installment': '5th Installment'}
{'installment': '6th Installment'}
{'installment': '7th Installment'}
```

the problem is that when i want to save my data into a csv file the first **{}** makes an empty row 
and this screw-up everyting

how can i get rid of the first {} and so i can get rid of the emtpy raw !?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Skip printing empty elements

Add a conditional to your code to only print elements that have content, e.g. as below.

```
if var:
  print(var)
```

(Empty dict's evaluate to False in python conditionals).

Comment: many thanks man i had this kind of validation i just had to press tab lol

Answer (score 0):

you can use default values from get function:

```
var = {}
for item in response.css('div.project-content  table tr'):
    var["installment"] = item.css(' td::text').extract_first()
    if var.get('installment', None) is not None:
        print(var)
```

This is an example with range values:

```
var = {}
for item in range(10):
    var["installment"] = None if item % 2 == 0 else item
    if var.get('installment', None) is not None:
        print(var)
--------- output ----
{'installment': 1}
{'installment': 3}
{'installment': 5}
{'installment': 7}
{'installment': 9}
```

Comment: actually, i am using **if "installment" in var:** . and thanks for sharing your codes here. I do appreciate it :)